# Unsure about what application of a paired t-test would be appropriate

Tags: t-test

I am currently working with 2 datasets for 2 different shoe types and am trying to compare factors like vertical ground reaction forces, loading rate, leg stiffness etc. Since each subject wore both shoes i opted to go with a paired t-test. The issue: i feel like there are 2 ways i can go about applying a paired t-test and am not sure which way would be more appropriate.

1. Compare the mean values for every category i am looking at. So for example <subject 1/shoe 1 mean loading rate> vs <subject 1/shoe 2 mean loading rate>. The issue i run into here is that with 8 subjects only that would make for a very small sample size and i am not sure if applying a t-test to a dataset that consists of of averages is a good practice.
2. Compare the bulk of steps with each other. So for example <subject 1/shoe 1 step 1 loading rate> vs <subject 1/shoe 2 step1 loading rate> and so on. The issue here is that since it was a timed trial every subject ran a different amount of steps so it could be 82 steps vs 87 steps. So in that case id get rid of the last 5 steps/rows to even out the data and be able to apply the paired t-test. But that would mean that id even out all the steps of all the subjects over all the trials so they are even in influence correct? So in the example before id bring subject 1-8 steps over both shoes to 82. I am just wondering if that would be the right way to go about it.

In the end my question listed again:

1. is it okay to apply a paired t-test to a dataset that consists of averages?
2. when comparing the actual steps with each other, that would mean that id have to even out all the steps over all subjects and all trials to match each other, correct?
3. would there be anything wrong with removing steps the way described in in question 2?

Statistics class has been a while for me. So thanks in advance!